# List of checked out files

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are using VSTS with Server Workspaces and enforce single user check-out locking.
I'd like to get a list of what files are currently checked out and to who.

Is that possible?

Note: we are using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition

Answer (score 5):

We cannot straightforward achieve that.

However you can run below commands in developer command prompt for visual studio to get the pending changes details. See [Status command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/status-command?view=vsts) for details.

1. Get the list of workspaces users have. This will provide you all the workspaces of the users in all the computers they have.

   `tf workspaces /computer:* /collection:https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`
2. List of what files are currently checked out (get all the
   pending changes) in all the workspaces using below command (*Just provide the specific workspace name if you want to retrieve the pending changes from a specific workspace*):

   ```
   tf stat $/0522TFVCScrum /recursive /collection:https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection /workspace:*
   ```
3. To get all changes from all users you can use command below:

   ```
   tf stat $/0522TFVCScrum /recursive /collection:https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection /user:*
   ```

You can also try the tool [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/), it can retrieve the status locked/checked out by other users. But unfortunately it's not support VS 2017, the latest version is `Version 6.0` only for **Visual Studio 2015**.

**But these will not retrieve the details about pending changes in a remote local workspace.**

[image]

[image]