# VSTS reporting capabilities

Tags: azure-devops

We're looking at moving from TFS to VSTS.  However, one of the features I rely on is the ability to see which developers have got code checked out, when it's getting checked in, and to which branch.  I need to see this at the collection level, not per project.  Does this functionality exist in VSTS?

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such built-in features in Azure DevOps (VSTS).

However you can try below workarounds:

- To see which developers have got code checked out, you can use the
  tool [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) which can retrieve the status
  locked/checked out by other users. But the latest version is `Version 6.0` only for Visual Studio 2015. Based on my test it's also available for VSTS. Please reference my answers in below threads:

  - [Is there a way in Visual Studio and TFS to view items checked out to local workspaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503330/is-there-a-way-in-visual-studio-and-tfs-to-view-items-checked-out-to-local-works/51516235#51516235)
  - [List of checked out files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607571/list-of-checked-out-files/50620435#50620435)
- For when it's getting checked in, and to which branch, you have to
  navigate to the specific repository to check the changesets which
  include the history. You can also try calling the REST API
  ([Changesets - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1)) to get the information.

Comment: OK.  This is helpful.  Thanks Andy.